Total return swap valuation of return leg
I have a question on valuing the return leg of a Total Return Swap (TRS).
Consider a TRS where I receive the return of an underlying bond (let's ignore default). The TRS was traded at time $t = 0$. At that time, the price of the bond was $B_0$.
We are now at $t=1$. What is the present value of the return leg?
My understanding is the following: Assume annual coupon payments, then I receive coupon payments ($C$ ) at year 2 and at year 3. At year 3, I also receive (or pay) the difference in bond price: $B_3 - B_0$, where $B_3$ is the bond price when the swap matures.
Assume discounting at a constant rate $r$, then the present value of the return leg at $t=1$ is:
$$PV_{leg,\ t=1} = C (1+r)^{-1} + C (1+r)^{-2} + \left(B_3 - B_0\right) (1+r)^{-2}$$
Is this correct so far?
What about the term $B_3 (1+r)^{-2}$. Isn't this simply the present value of the bond at time $t=1$?
Thus suppose at time $t=1$, this bond has 50 years remaining. Does the following hold?
$$B_3 (1+r)^{-2} = \sum_{k=1}^{49}C (1+r)^{-k} + (1+C)(1+r)^{-50} = PV_{bond,\ t=1}$$
And thus:
$$PV_{leg,\ t=1} = C (1+r)^{-1} + C (1+r)^{-2} + PV_{bond,\ t=1} - B_0 (1+r)^{-2}$$
Or am now double counting those two coupon payments somehow?
Thanks.

Isn't it just the dirty price of the underlying bond?
